# Why does a bare-metal app crash on the entrypoint function?

Tags: c, assembly, raspberry-pi3, arm64, bare-metal

I have a small bare-metal app for **Raspberry PI 3B** (emulating by Qemu) and, unfortunately, it crashes in some cases but first let's I will show my code.

**kernel.c:**

```
#include "stdio.h" // It's a custom header, not from stdlib

void run() {
    enable_mini_uart();
    volatile ulong_t * aux_mu_io_reg = (volatile ulong_t *)AUX_MU_IO_REG;
    *aux_mu_io_reg = 'V';
}
```

**loader.s:**

```
.global _start

.section ".text"
// Entrypoint
_start:
    // First 8 bits of MPIDR_EL1 indicate core ID
    MRS     X1, MPIDR_EL1
    AND     X1, X1, 0x0f
    CBZ     X1, _cpu_0
// Loop non-zero CPU
_cpu_x:
    // Wait for event
    WFE
    B       _cpu_x

// Continue with zero CPU
_cpu_0:
    BL      run
```

**linker.ld:**

```
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS {
    . = 0x80000;
    .text : { *(.text) }
}
```

And finally **Makefile**:

```
# Build directory path
BUILD_DIR=build
# Toolchain path
BINTOOLS_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aarch64-elf-binutils/2.41/bin
# LLVM path
LLVM_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
# Qemu path
QEMU_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qemu/8.1.1
# Tools aliases
OBJCOPY=$(LLVM_PATH)/llvm-objcopy
OBJDUMP=$(LLVM_PATH)/llvm-objdump
HEXDUMP=hexdump
CC=$(LLVM_PATH)/clang
AS=$(BINTOOLS_PATH)/aarch64-elf-as
LD=$(BINTOOLS_PATH)/aarch64-elf-ld
# Headers and sources paths
HEADER_PATH=include
SRC_PATH=src
# C sources
C_SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_PATH)/*.c)
# ASM sources
ASM_SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_PATH)/*.s)
# C objects
C_OBJS := $(C_SRCS:$(SRC_PATH)/%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
# ASM objects
ASM_OBJS := $(ASM_SRCS:$(SRC_PATH)/%.s=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
# C targets
C_TARGETS := $(C_SRCS:$(SRC_PATH)/%.c=%)
# ASM targets
ASM_TARGETS := $(ASM_SRCS:$(SRC_PATH)/%.s=%)

# Default target
all: mkdir kernel_img

# Target to build a binary kernel
kernel_img: kernel_elf
    $(OBJCOPY) $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.elf -O binary $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.img

# Target to build an ELF kernel
kernel_elf: $(ASM_TARGETS) $(C_TARGETS)
    $(LD) -m aarch64elf -nostdlib -T linker.ld $(ASM_OBJS) $(C_OBJS) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.elf

# Target to compile loader.s
$(ASM_TARGETS): %: $(SRC_PATH)/%.s
    $(AS) $< -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@.o

# Targets to compile C sources
$(C_TARGETS): %: $(SRC_PATH)/%.c
    $(CC) -c \
        --target=aarch64-none-linux \
        -Wall \
        -O2 \
        -fomit-frame-pointer \
        -fno-exceptions \
        -Wno-incompatible-library-redeclaration \
        -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables \
        -fno-unwind-tables \
        -I$(HEADER_PATH) \
        -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@.o $<

# Target to ensure if the build directory was created
mkdir:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

# Target to dump an ELF kernel
dump:
    $(OBJDUMP) -D $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.elf

# Target to dump a binary kernel
dump_img:
    $(HEXDUMP) -C $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.img

# Target to run Qemu in debug mode
debug:
    qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3b \
        -display none \
        -serial null \
        -serial stdio \
        -kernel $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.elf \
        -s \
        -S

# Target to connect a debugger to the Qemu in debug mode
debugger:
    lldb $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.elf

# Target to run Qemu
run:
    qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3b \
        -display none \
        -serial null \
        -serial stdio \
        -kernel $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.elf

# Target to clean all temporal files
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o
```

What's happening... If I build this app the compiler generates the next code:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-objdump -D build/kernel.elf

build/kernel.elf:       file format elf64-littleaarch64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000080000 <_start>:
   80000: d53800a1      mrs     x1, MPIDR_EL1
   80004: 92400c21      and     x1, x1, #0xf
   80008: b4000061      cbz     x1, 0x80014 <_cpu_0>

000000000008000c <_cpu_x>:
   8000c: d503205f      wfe
   80010: 17ffffff      b       0x8000c <_cpu_x>

0000000000080014 <_cpu_0>:
   80014: 9400000c      bl      0x80044 <run>

... # Skipping a some code

0000000000080044 <run>:
   80044: f81f0ffe      str     x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
   80048: 9400000b      bl      0x80074 <enable_mini_uart>
   8004c: 528a0808      mov     w8, #0x5040             // =20544
   80050: 72a7e428      movk    w8, #0x3f21, lsl #16
   80054: 52800ac9      mov     w9, #0x56               // =86
   80058: f9000109      str     x9, [x8]
   8005c: f84107fe      ldr     x30, [sp], #0x10
   80060: d65f03c0      ret

0000000000080064 <read_mmio>:
   80064: f9400000      ldr     x0, [x0]
   80068: d65f03c0      ret

000000000008006c <write_mmio>:
   8006c: f9000001      str     x1, [x0]
   80070: d65f03c0      ret

0000000000080074 <enable_mini_uart>:
   80074: 528a0c08      mov     w8, #0x5060             // =20576
   80078: 52800029      mov     w9, #0x1                // =1
   8007c: 72a7e428      movk    w8, #0x3f21, lsl #16
   80080: 5280006a      mov     w10, #0x3               // =3
   80084: 528000cb      mov     w11, #0x6               // =6
   80088: f81a4109      stur    x9, [x8, #-0x5c]
   8008c: 528021c9      mov     w9, #0x10e              // =270
   80090: f900011f      str     xzr, [x8]
   80094: f81e411f      stur    xzr, [x8, #-0x1c]
   80098: f81ec10a      stur    x10, [x8, #-0x14]
   8009c: f81f011f      stur    xzr, [x8, #-0x10]
   800a0: f9000509      str     x9, [x8, #0x8]
   800a4: f81e810b      stur    x11, [x8, #-0x18]
   800a8: f900010a      str     x10, [x8]
   800ac: d65f03c0      ret
```

Let's look at `run()` closer:

```
0000000000080044 <run>:
       # Control the stack
       80044: f81f0ffe      str     x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
       # Call `enable_mini_uart(void)`
       80048: 9400000b      bl      0x80074 <enable_mini_uart>
       # Print `V` to miniUART
       8004c: 528a0808      mov     w8, #0x5040             // =20544
       80050: 72a7e428      movk    w8, #0x3f21, lsl #16
       80054: 52800ac9      mov     w9, #0x56               // =86
       80058: f9000109      str     x9, [x8]
       # Control the stack
       8005c: f84107fe      ldr     x30, [sp], #0x10
       # Return
       80060: d65f03c0      ret
```

When I run this code it crashes on `80044: f81f0ffe` line and I can't get why. Also I can't understand why compiler tries to control the stack in this case, seems there are no reasons for that.

If I won't call `enable_mini_uart()` and will paste its code directly into the `run()` then the compiler doesn't try to control the stack and my app prints `V` on the screen.

I don't understand at all why the compiler adds these lines in the first case and why it crashes on start.

**P.S.** I use LLVM on MacBook Pro (M1 Pro) to compile the app.

Comment: I'd suspect a wrong stack location or missing something to set it properly before doing anything else.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre can you explain about "wrong stack location" more, plz? I am a noobie in low level programming still, unfortunately, so it's hard to understand some moments.

Comment: Where does `sp` point to per default after a reset? Is there some memory available? Otherwise you might need to set it to some valid address before you jump to `run` function.

Comment: @Gerhardh you are right, I didn't setup the stack pointer, I didn't know even.

Comment: Thank you for help, guys, I'll try get how to setup a stack pointer and will return with results. I hope it will help

Comment: @Gerhardh it is not after reset. This after bootstraping. So SP is set somewhere logical as the bootstrap code had to set it, initialize the vectors + some other things to start loading and executing this image

Comment: After setting the stack pointer the app began to work! Yet one time thank you for your comments, guys!

Comment: The "controlling the stack" is merely the function pushing the return address (saved in `x30` by `bl`) onto the stack, and popping it off at the end.  That's entirely normal!  It's necessary because the function call to `enable_mini_uart` will overwrite `x30`, so we have to save the return address in order to be able to return later.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thank you for explaining!